# Recover overwritten PowerPoint 07 file from temp?

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2007

What is the full path of the temporary office 07 directory on windows vista or windows seven?  A PowerPoint presentation was overwritten, are there any other options besides checking the said temp folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might check Volume Shadow Copy (File -> Properties -> Older Versions).
As far as temporary files, you might look in
`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.<officeapp>\` where `<officeapp>` is "Word" or "PowerPoint".
Depending on how critical the file is, you might also try DiskInternal's office recovery applications, I've found them to be excellent in personal use.

Comment: Vol shadow copy did not work. Unwashed looking for that path, thanks.